# Raw Binary Tree Database or MongoDb/MySQL/Etc?

Tags: c++, mysql, mongodb, b-tree, database

I will be storing terabytes of information, before indexes, and after compression methods.

Should I code up a Binary Tree Database by hand using sort files etc, or use something like MongoDB or even something like MySQL?

I am worried about (space) cost per record with things like MySQL and other DB's that are around.  I also know that some databases even allow for compression, but they convert to read only tables.  These tables/records need to be accessed and overwritten with new data fairly often.  I think if I were to code something in C++ I'd be able to keep the cost of space per record to a minimum.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are new non-relational databases that are becoming popular these days, that specialize in managing large-scale data.

Check out [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) or [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/), both of these are at the Apache Project.